# Angular 15 multiple auxiliary routes in featured module throws warnings

Tags: angular, angular-auxiliary-routes

I have 3 router-outlets:

- primary
- router-outlet (detail)
- router-outlet (visited)

All the routes are configured in the featured module 'country'. Click a country on the left side, and you will see the details on the right side, and a 'last visited' log at the bottom. This is only to showcase multiple auxiliary routes, so I am aware that i could accomplish this in many different ways..

clip from the gui:
[image]

country.routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'country', component: CountryComponent, children: [
    {path: '', children: [
      {path: '', component: CountryMasterComponent},
      {path: ':name', outlet: 'detail', component: CountryDetailComponent},
      {path: 'messages', outlet: 'visited', component: CountryVisitedComponent}
    
    ]},
  ]},  
];
```

Calling the detail from the master:
<`a [routerLink]="['../country', { outlets: { detail: [country.name] } }]">`

In the country.detail component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router, private apiService: RestApiService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.country$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.apiService.getCountry(params.get('name')!))
    );
    
  }
```

In the apiService:

```
getCountry(name: string): Observable<Country> {
    const c$ = this.getAllCountries(false).pipe(map((countries: Country[]) => 
      countries.find(country => country.name === name)!)
    );
    if(c$) {
      this.messageService.addMessage("Fetched county: "+name);
    }
    return c$;
  }
}
```

Finally inside the messageService:

```
addMessage(msg: string): void {
  this.messages.push(msg);
  this.router.navigate(['../country', { outlets: {visited: ['messages']}}]);
}
```

The URL seems fine to me:

> http://localhost:4200/country/(visited:messages//detail:Turkey)

and everything works as expected, as you can see from the attached image, however, I get the following warnings in the console, and I can't really find anything on this anywhere:

> country-master.component.html:6 The navigation to
> /country/(detail:Turkey//visited:messages) will instead go to
> /(detail:Turkey//visited:messages) in an upcoming version of Angular.
> `relativeTo` might need to be removed from the `UrlCreationOptions`.
>
> message.service.ts:23 The navigation to
> /country/(visited:messages//detail:Turkey) will instead go to
> /(visited:messages//detail:Turkey) in an upcoming version of Angular.

So the question is - How can I resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a just warning that has landed in 15.2 to warn about a breaking change that will happen in v16.

See [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48688) for more info.

This is nothing to do on your side for the moment !

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the warning - some kind of tslint maybe?

Comment: No there isn't, but the warning message will be striped out in a prod build.

Comment: Great Matt - I'll live with it in debug until the breaking in ver. 16, then I might have to refactor...